# If Returns Value Then Include </br> If no Value Returned then No </br>

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, null

```
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('contactname', '<strong>Contact: ', '</strong>'); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('address', '', '</br>'); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('mailingaddress', '', ''); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('Town', '', ', MB'); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('phone_1', 'Phone:', ''); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('phone_2', 'Phone:', ''); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('phone_tollfree', 'Toll Free:', ''); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('email', 'Email:', ''); ?></br>
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('website', 'Website:', ''); ?></br>
```

How do I have it so that if There is no Value for the phone_2 Value that the `</br>` isn't there after . . .or basically if the value is null to have no `</br>`

I am guessing this will be an if statement, I am just BRAND new to all of this. . .

Comment: Forgot to Write proper Code it should say '</br>'

Comment: If you made a mistake, you can click on the `edit` button to edit your post above.

Comment: `</br>` isn't valid in any HTML spec.

Comment: <br /> is the valid HTML equivalent.

Comment: <br /> is only valid pending on which format of HTML your site is supporting. XHTML Transitional Strict (or traditional? I can't remember off hand) <br /> would be valid, where as in html5 <br> is valid. They will both do the same thing while rendering in a browser but if you tell the WWW your site is Strict, Transitional, or other form of HTML compliance then stick to that particular compliance format. w3.org has a wealth of info on standards of the web. and you can validate your mark up there too http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: `<br>` is the classic HTML version. For XML compatibility i.e. XHTML) you need to use either `<br />` or `<br></br>`. A `</br>` without a preceding `<br>` may actually be ignored by many parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the function is such:

```
function c2c_get_custom( 
    $field, 
    $before='', 
    $after='', 
    $none='', 
    $between='', 
    $before_last=''
)
```

Acquired from here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-custom-field-values/other_notes/

Therefore each line should look similar to this:

```
c2c_get_custom('phone_2', 'Phone:', '<br />', '');
```

If the above does not work then the following should suffice:

```
<?php 
   $phone2 = c2c_get_custom('phone_2', 'Phone:', ''); 
   echo (is_null($phone2) || $phone2 == '' ? '' : $phone2.'<br />')
?>
```

Comment: Great, make use of the first one as this is the way the function was intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$phone2 = c2c_get_custom('phone_2', 'Phone:', '');
if (!empty ($phone2)) {
    echo $phone2 . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Note: I also changed `</br>` to `<br />` since you can't use br like that. (well, you shouldn't)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone2 = c2c_get_custom('phone_2', 'Phone:', '');

/*You can use an if statement like: */
if(is_null($phone2) || !isset($phone2))
{
    print "no" . "<>";
}
else
{
    print $phone2;
}

/* or you can also do: */

print (is_null($phone2) || !isset($phone2)) ? "no" : $phone2;

/*You can add in your </br> anywhere needed here. 
Also if your trying to put a line break there, its <br /> and not </br>*/
```